# Testing component with react-router v4, Jest and Enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jestjs

I have a simple component that uses react-router (I'm aware this is the alpha build):

```
{props.app && props.app.health &&
   <Match exactly pattern="/" component={HomeLogin} />
}
```

The docs recommending wrapping in `<MemoryRouter />` to provide context to components while testing.

However, with Jest/Enzyme I'm not able to `shallow()` render - I have to use Enzyme's `mount()` or `render()`, which causes problems because `HomeLogin` is a connected component - I want to be able to test that my component renders the right thing, but *not* test the component rendered within it.

My test:

```
it('Renders based upon matched route', () => {
  let props = {
    app: { health: true },
  };
  const component = render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <MemoryRouter location="/">
        <Jumbotron {...props} />
      </MemoryRouter>
    </Provider>
  );
  expect(toJson(component)).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

How can I test the output of this component based upon the route without having to provide the redux store or using shallow render?

*Update:* If I try to use `shallow()` the snapshot renders no output.

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.find(Jumbotron)` and use that for matching as snapshot, for example:

```
const wrapped = component.find(Jumbotron);
expect(toJson(wrapped)).toMatchSnapshot();
```

I had a more complex example involving `withRouter()` and I was restoring to removing all keys from the output before matching as snapshot. Well, until testing for React-Router v4 gets more solid with Jest and snapshot testing. Example:

```
export function removeKeys(object) {
    if (object === undefined || object === null) {
        return object;
    }
    Object.keys(object).forEach((key) => {
        if (typeof object[key] === 'object') {
            removeKeys(object[key]);
        } else if (key === 'key') {
           delete object[key];
        }
    });
    return object;
}

...

expect(removeKeys(toJson(component))).toMatchSnapshot();
```